# lider see through wall

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i start gmapping with lider it see through wall
[image: image description]

there is a wall behind it it shows a gap which really messes up the map

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379505/lider-see-through-wall/) by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2021-06-03

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i got the solution i just have to replace this

replace

```
<sensor type="gpu_ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
```

with

```
<sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
```

and replace

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
```

with

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
```

---

Originally posted by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) with karma: 74 on 2021-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0